# Enforce inserting a record into a secondary table every time a record is inserted into a primary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parent-child, sql-insert

In a SQL Server 2008 R2 setup, I have `table1 (id, col1-1, col1-2, ...)` and `table2 (id, table1_id, col2-1, col2-2, ...)`, where `table2.table1_id` points to `table1.id` (i.e. a foreign key to primary key relation).

How do I enforce the rule that every time somebody insert a record into `table1`, they are also required to create a record into `table2`?

I would guess that the obvious mechanism to use here are triggers, but this can lead to the chicken and the egg problem since the trigger will require a record in `table2` in order to create a record in `table1`, but in order to create a record in `table2` first I need the `table1.id` value to already exists. How to overcome this?

I need the enforcement to be automatic and built-in into the database. A frequently running job to check for records in `table1` without corresponding records in `table2` will not make the cut and the rule must be enforced at real time when somebody is actually creating a record in `table1`.

Comment: Although not "automatic and built-in", if you provide a stored procedure to implement `AddMultitableStuff`, grant it write access to the tables and deny users write access to the tables then you can control how rows are added with arbitrary business rules.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause to do that. Here is a simple example

```
CREATE TABLE Parent(Id INT, Col VARCHAR(45));
CREATE TABLE Child(Id INT, Col VARCHAR(45));

INSERT INTO Parent(Id, Col)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, INSERTED.Col INTO Child
VALUES(1, 'SomeValue');
  
SELECT *
FROM Parent P
JOIN Child C ON P.Id = C.Id;
```

Note that the extended support for SQL Server 2008/2008 R2 ends on July 9, 2019. You should upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Chicken and the egg problem is preventable, but I tested on Windows SQL 2016:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Table1_Insert]
       ON [dbo].[Table1RR] AFTER INSERT
    AS
    IF rowcount_big() = 0 RETURN --leave trigger if no record (-s) inserted in the Table1
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Table2RR NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Table2_Table1 -- resolve chicken and the egg problem 
    INSERT INTO dbo.Table2RR select id,null,null from inserted order by id
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Table2RR CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Table2_Table1
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1RR] ENABLE TRIGGER [Table1_Insert]
    GO
```